# Access WSDL WebService in Android?

Tags: android, wsdl

I am new in android. I need to access wsdl webservice with android. If anybody have tried it please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer WSClient for Android

Comment: hey let me know is there any sample progarm or tutorial for this?

Comment: hi ,please refer ksoap,it has all methods to access webservice.Refer this,"http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html"

Comment: the link in comment is broken